# Build API Function

Tags: functions, dynamic, apifunction

If I want to create an API function that takes two numbers a and b and returns an image. This image is supposed to be dynamically embedded on a web page that collects a and b and passes the values to the APIFunction. However, the webpage requires the URL of the image to end with ".png" (image format), for example https://something{{a}}{{b}}.png.

I created and deployed an APIFunction and retrieved an URL https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/myurl  (i.e. the URL does not end with ".png")

What do I need to do in order to make the embedded dynamic image API work?

Comment: `https://something{{a}}{{b}}.png` is not a valid url ({{}}), can you add a viable example?

Comment: 1)This cannot be achieved with an APIFunction. 2)In the APIFunction specify a and b as images. 3)In CloudDeploy of the APIFunction use "PNG" as the format of the deployed CloudObject (outside the APIFunction).4)In CloudDeploy of the APIFunction use "*.png" as the named object. (* can be any string, for example https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/myurl.png).5)In the APIFunction specify a as a "String" and drop the last 4 characters of a, then call ...myurl?a={{a}}&b={{b}}.png. 6)In the APIFunction specify b as a "String" and drop the last 4 characters of b, then call ...myurl?a={{a}}&b={{b}}.png

Comment: This are the option I can choose

Comment: One possible way is to create a Node.js wrapper around Wolfram API. Server.js could load the image from Wolfram API and return the same but with a link ending with jpg. Same can be achieved in PHP using URL rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extended comment. This seems to be a task for `URLDispatcher` but as soon as the url contains a file extension the Cloud responds with 500 internal error.

Without file extension:

```
obj = CloudDeploy[
  URLDispatcher[{
    ("/" ~~ a : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "/" ~~ b : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "/image" ) :> 
      ExportForm[Rasterize @ Framed[ToExpression@a + ToExpression@b], "PNG"] 
  }],
  "myurl"
]
```

```
obj[[1]] <> "/1/5/image" // URLRead // Import
```

> [image]

As mentioned with `/image.png` it fails.

Comment: I reported it and it is confirmed as an issue that does not not have a workaround atm.